# How resize layer Mask inside custom tableview cell for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6Plus devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer, iphone-6

I created custom tableview cell

```
@implementation AccountNewsCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        CustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [CustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0 blue:196.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        self.accessoryView =accessory;

        UIView * backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewForBaselineLayout.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        backgroundView.alpha=0.6;
        [self setBackgroundView:[self viewWithMask:backgroundView]];
    }
    return self;
}


-(UIView *) viewWithMask:(UIView *)view
{
    UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(7, 1, view.frame.size.width-14, 40) cornerRadius: 5];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = roundedRectanglePath.CGPath;
    [view.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    return view;

}
```

Code of creation tableview cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"news";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundView=[[AccountNewsCell alloc] init];
        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView=[self viewWithMask:selectedBackgroundView];
        return cell;
}
```

In iphone 4,5,5s when screen width 320pt it works fine
[image]
But in new device it works bad. I don't know how increase mask size in this case.
[image]
[image]
How i can fix this bug?

Comment: I found solution by reading screen size inside cell `-initWithFrame` function
`CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
 result = CGSizeMake(result.width , result.height);
 UIView * backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, result.width, 44)]`.
May be exist another solution?